# Do a specific action in Selenium depending on the type of web selector

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I have a web page that contains numerous blocks with a text field, drop-down menus, etc.

I need a method, that evaluates the type of the web selector and does exact actions if the selector name matches a pattern.

I have a SpecFlow feature file

```
Scenario: Scenario name
When I do this
And I do that
And I do that
And I do that
And I filled in the form

    | Field       | Field            | Field  | 
    | value       | value            | value  |
```

And the C# code

```
[When(@"I filled in the form")]
    public void WhenFillTheForm(Table table)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < table.Header.Count(); i++)
        {
            var elementName = table.Header.ElementAt(i);
            var elementValue = table.Rows[0].Values.ElementAt(i);
            var textField =
                driver.FindElement(
                    By.XPath($"//label[contains(text(),'{elementName}')]//following::textarea[1]"));
            textField.SendKeys(elementValue);
            driver.WaitFor(0.1);

            var dropDown =
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//label[contains(text(),'{elementName}')]/following::input[1]"));

            dropDown.SendKeys(elementValue);
            driver.WaitFor(2);
            dropDown.SendKeys(Keys.Down);
            dropDown.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        }
```

HTML code of the `textarea` type element

```
<textarea data-v-29bdb854="" rows="2" name="combatExperience" autocomplete="off" class="el-textarea__inner form-control"></textarea>
```

[image: Textarea]

HTML code of the `input` type element

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Choose" class="el-input__inner" wtx-context="A120D40C-D388-40CD-88DE-9CD2C5B270E0">
```

[image: Input]

Both have the exact same locator body `//label[contains(text(),'{elementName}')]//following::textarea[1]` The only difference is the final part of a selector `textarea` and `input`.

This code repeats and fills unnecessary fields. I want to perform specific actions regardless of the name of the selector.

Comment: I am unclear about what you mean by "I want to perform specific actions regardless of the name of the selector". The step looks like it does something generic, but you want to do something specific? Can you describe more about the "specific actions" you need to automate?

Comment: As you can see from my code, Greg, I want to enter text in some text fields. In another case, I want to enter the text and choose the option from a drop-down menu.

Comment: Ok. So in some cases you have an `<input>` plus a `<select>`, and in other cases you have an `<input>` and and `<input>`? Can you add some representative HTML code to illustrate what you are working with?

Comment: Or are you trying to do something with a `<textarea>` or `<input>`?

Comment: Greg, I have updated my original question. In one case I have `<textarea>` to fill the text in the text field. In another case, I have `<input>` to fill the text and then select an option from a drop-down menu.

Comment: The `<input>` tag is readonly. You cannot type in that field, so a call to `SendKeys` in Selenium will throw an exception. If the input really is readonly at runtime, then there is no way for you to do what you want, even if you can create the correct Selenium locator.

Comment: Actually, I can. For some reason, I find the `<input>`, enter the value without any exception. After I see a drop-down menu and I can choose an element from it. Should I provide screenshots?

Comment: We need to see more HTML, and maybe even a screenshot of part of the page. See [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405792/3092298).

Comment: Greg, even more information has been added.

Comment: So does typing in one field cause the other field to become enabled?

Comment: Nope. These two (and in the future more) fields are completely independent. My idea is to combine actions (fill, chose, etc.) with different types of fields based on their XPath selector name.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you are asking about. Do you want an XPath selector that identifies a textarea or an input so you can treat each element the same later on?

Comment: I want to create a method, which can evaluate the type of actions to be performed with an element based on its type. If XPath locator ends with textarea - do these steps, if not - do these steps.

Comment: Ok, I *think* I know what you are aiming for. I will attempt an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of detecting differences in the XPath expression, you can use `element.TagName` to differentiate between `<textarea>` and `<input>` elements.

```
var xpath = "(//label[contains(text(),'{elementName}')]//following::textarea[1])"
          + "|"
          + "(//label[contains(text(),'{elementName}')]//following::input[1])";

var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));

if (element.TagName == "input")
{
    // do something specific with an <input> element
}
else if (element.TagName == "textarea")
{
    // do something specific with a <textarea> element
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Fix the XPath");
}
```

The `|` character is an "OR" operator. The XPath expression is basically `(A)|(B)` so it will match either a `<textarea>` or `<input>`. Without more guidance on what the HTML looks like or what you would like to do in each case, this is all I can provide.

Comment: Greg, I did some code with my team lead. Please, see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Specflow step. Here add an XPath to a collection. Then we evaluate what action to perform with a specific locator. Fill or fill with additional steps. This test now reduces the manual testing job from 1h30m to 20 minutes.

```
 [When(@"I filled in the form")]
    public void WhenFillTheForm(Table table)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < table.Header.Count(); i++)
        {
            var elementName = table.Header.ElementAt(i);
            var elementValue = table.Rows[0].Values.ElementAt(i);

            var xpathList = new List<string>();
            var textAreaLocator = $"//label[contains(text(),'{elementName}')]//parent::div//following-sibling::textarea[1]";
            var inputLocator = $"//label[contains(text(),'{elementName}')]//parent::div//following-sibling::input";
            var textAreaLocatorWithoutParentNode = $"//label[contains(text(),'{elementName}')]//following::textarea[1]";
            xpathList.Add(textAreaLocator);
            xpathList.Add(inputLocator);
            xpathList.Add(textAreaLocatorWithoutParentNode);

            var element = driver.FindElementByAnyXpath(xpathList);
            if (element.TagName == "input")
            {
                element.SendKeys(elementValue);
                element.SendKeys(Keys.Down);
                element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
            }
            else if (element.TagName == "textarea")
            {
                element.SendKeys(elementValue);
            }
           
            driver.WaitFor(0.1);
        }
    }
```

`FindElementByAnyXpath` method to find an XPath

```
 public static IWebElement FindElementByAnyXpath(this IWebDriver driver, IEnumerable<string> xPathCollection)
    {
        foreach (var selector in xPathCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(selector));
                return element;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First time doing this so I might be way off!

I've done something similar using a switch statement  - hopefully this looks right.

```
switch (elementName)
{
    case: "do this":
    Do something
    break;
    case: "do that":
    Do the other thing
    break;
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? This is not enough information for the OP to solve their problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no. This `switch` doesn't allow me to elaborate on which type of element I get.